# NSMutableParagraphStyle remove old NSMutableAttributedString from UITextView

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I try to add bullet point into UITextView in the start of the text but when i Add with this code the old attributedString and font and size not saved.

in this code :

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:currentTextViewEdit.text];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [paragrahStyle setParagraphSpacing:4];
        [paragrahStyle setParagraphSpacingBefore:3];
        [paragrahStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:0.0f];  // First line is the one with bullet point
        [paragrahStyle setHeadIndent:10.5f];    // Set the indent for given bullet character and size font


        [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentTextViewEdit.text length])];


        currentTextViewEdit.attributedText = attributedString;

        currentTextViewEdit.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.%@",currentTextViewEdit.text];
```

I try to add a NSMutableParagraphStyle but its remove the old NSMutableAttributedString that text have before.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:@"1."]; [attributedString appendAttributedString:currentTextViewEdit.attributedText];`
And don't do `currentTextViewEdit.text =`. afterward.